# Pagination over union with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

This is my query:

```
select * from (
    select u.id, 'u' as [type], u.firstName, u.lastName, c.name as companyName,
        u.lastName + u.firstName + isNull(c.name, '') as sortName
    from users as u
        left outer join companies as c on c.id = u.company_id

    union all

    select id, 'c' as [type], null as firstName, null as lastName, name as 
        companyName, name as sortName
    from companies
) as result
where sortName like '%a%'
order by sortName
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

It returns 10 rows from the tables `users` and `companies` which matches the search string "a". With the offset/fetch I can easily do pagination in my application. But what I still need to know, is how many rows are in the database which matches the search string "a" without the fetch limit.

My first approach was a `count(*)` over the result query, but this doesn't work (because of the union I guess).

Comment: Why do you mean when you say using `COUNT(*) OVER()` does not work? This should work in this query ---- `SELECT object_id, Count = COUNT(*) OVER() FROM (SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects UNION ALL SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects) AS t WHERE t.Name LIKE 's%' ORDER BY object_id OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;` ---- the count is correct

Comment: I was using `count(*)` without the `over()` and that didn't work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, I misread your question. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Its better to create a `VIEW` with the `UNION` query provided. Then from that you can `COUNT(*)` the records and display it further for front ent

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the COUNT(*) OVER() in you select * statement like the below. The total number of rows will be in the new column called "total_rows" in the example below.

```
select *, total_rows=COUNT(*) OVER() from (
    select u.id, 'u' as [type], u.firstName, u.lastName, c.name as companyName,
        u.lastName + u.firstName + isNull(c.name, '') as sortName
    from users as u
        left outer join companies as c on c.id = u.company_id

    union all

    select id, 'c' as [type], null as firstName, null as lastName, name as 
        companyName, name as sortName
    from companies
) as result
where sortName like '%a%'
order by sortName
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```